# How to install graph-tool

Tags: graph-tool

I met problem when I "make" in graph-tool-2.19. Part of the problem is shown in the link. Do you know how to deal with it?

**problem 1**

[image]

**problem 2**

[image]

Comment: Did you try using the pre-compiled binaries?

Comment: I can see the installation platform is MacOsX. I recommend to use `MacPorts`. Otherwise, you need to deal with high number of dependencies manually. It will take so much time